# HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized

Tags: iis

Hi I am trying to consume a web service on a mobile emulator. But I always have this error everytime I add a web reference - "HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized". I already added the web site on the IIS manager 6.0. Is there an easy way to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 41):

IIS needs access permissions for **IUSR** user too... add this user. 
If you don't know how, see the link

The same problem solved [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/38222/iis-7-5-windows-7-http-error-401-3-unauthorized)

Answer (score 36):

Enable Anonymous Authentication for the web site, then Edit Anonymous Authentication (by right clicking) and change it from a Specific User to Application pool identity

Answer (score 17):

Give IIS_IUSR and IUSR permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that application pool of your website and website both are running under the same identity. Then make sure that this identity has required permissions on the virtual directory. I had exact same issue and above two checks fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

Go to the following link, you can get more info about the error:

http://forums.iis.net/p/1048841/1477558.aspx